# Alarm Tutorial : alarmDetails Cannot resolve as a variable

Tags: android, alarm

I Know this a silly question, but I am really new on android development. I have followed tutorial about making a simple alarm on this website [Create an Alarm Clock in Android](http://www.steventrigg.com/create-an-alarm-clock-in-android-tutorial-part-2/) but I think the autor forgot to write some variable line, because I got error in few lines like this `alarmDetails cannot resolve as a variable` in every line include `alarmDetails`. I have no idea what the variable type of that line, here is the complete code :

**Update** Problem solved, but I got another error : `alarmTone cannot resolve as a field` . I think it's the same problem, some of the code is not put on the tutorial. Here is the code of my class `AlarmDetailsActivity`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.widget.*;
import android.net.Uri;
import dev.serabutan.socioalarm.AlrmModel;

public class AlarmDetailsActivity extends Activity {


    AlrmModel alarmDetails; 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm_details);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Create New Alarm");
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final LinearLayout ringToneContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.alarm_ringtone_container);
    ringToneContainer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
    }
Uri alarmTone;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch (requestCode){
                case 1:{

                    alarmDetails.alarmTone = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
                    //it's says error : alarmTone Cannot resolve as a field
                    TextView txtToneSelection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_label_tone_selection);
                    txtToneSelection.setText(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarmDetails.alarmTone).getTitle(this));
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alarm_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:{
                finish();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.action_save_alarm_details:{
                updateModelFromLayout();
                finish();
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void updateModelFromLayout() {

    TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_time_picker);
    alarmDetails.timeMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute().intValue();
    alarmDetails.timeHour = timePicker.getCurrentHour().intValue();

    EditText edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_name);
    alarmDetails.name = edtName.getText().toString();

    CheckBox chkWeekly = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_weekly);
    alarmDetails.repeatWeekly = chkWeekly.isChecked();

    CheckBox chkSunday = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_sunday);
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlrmModel.SUNDAY, chkSunday.isChecked());

    CheckBox chkMonday = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_monday);
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlrmModel.MONDAY, chkMonday.isChecked());

    CheckBox chkTuesday = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_tuesday);
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlrmModel.TUESDAY, chkTuesday.isChecked());

    CheckBox chkWednesday = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_wednesday);
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlrmModel.WEDNESDAY, chkWednesday.isChecked());

    CheckBox chkThursday = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_thursday);
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlrmModel.THURSDAY, chkThursday.isChecked());

    CheckBox chkFriday = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_friday);
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlrmModel.FRIDAY, chkFriday.isChecked());

    CheckBox chkSaturday = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alarm_details_repeat_saturday);
    alarmDetails.setRepeatingDay(AlrmModel.SATURDAY, chkSaturday.isChecked());

    alarmDetails.isEnabled = true;
}


}
```

and this code for class AlarmModel

```
import android.net.Uri;

public class AlrmModel{

    public static final int SUNDAY = 0;
    public static final int MONDAY = 1;
    public static final int TUESDAY = 2;
    public static final int WEDNESDAY = 3;
    public static final int THURSDAY = 4;
    public static final int FRIDAY = 5;
    public static final int SATURDAY = 6;

    public long id;
    public int timeHour;
    public int timeMinute;
    private boolean repeatingDays[];
    public boolean repeatWeekly;
    public String name;
    public boolean isEnabled;

    public AlrmModel(){
        repeatingDays = new boolean[7];
    }

    public void setRepeatingDay(int dayOfWeek, boolean value){
        repeatingDays[dayOfWeek] = value;
    }

    public boolean getRepeatingDay(int dayOfWeek){
        return repeatingDays[dayOfWeek];
    }
}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Looks like alarmDetails variable belongs to AlarmModel.class

Comment: but, how to create new variable in this class from othe class (AlarmModel class) ?

Comment: Wow thanks, its work. just placed `AlarmModel alarmDetails;` but its a little error like this `alarmTone cannot resolve as a type`. What the type field or variable for `alarmTone` ?

Comment: Still not work, it's says `alarmTone cannot resolve as a field`

Comment: Could you update question with changes that you made? (also, please, include AlarmModel.class)

Comment: Yes, i have updtaed my question. see above

Comment: alarmTone has to be field of AlarmModel.class. Also you should create instance of AlarmModel class to avoid NPE.

Comment: According to my code, how i create instance of AlarmModel class to avoid NPE ? i mean the full code of what your suggest. Sorry because im really new in android development

Comment: just add AlrmModel alarmDetails = new AlrmModel();

Comment: Done, but `alarmTone` still not verify as a field.

Comment: Did you put alarmTone field into AlrmModel.class?

Comment: Oh my... my bad. I forget some line, forget variable `alarmTone` on AlrmModel.class. it's terrible, thanks for your answers, Nickolai. Very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try AlarmModel: in the tutorial, the variables in AlarmModel seem to match that of alarmDetails

Comment: but, how to create new variable in this class from othe class (AlarmModel class) ?

Comment: Thanks, its work.but i got another error like this `alarmTone cannot resolve as a type`. What the type field or variable for `alarmTone` ?